# Radeon HD 7730M GPU driver not working on XUbuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, radeon, amdgpu

So I moved my harddrive from one laptop that had an NVIDIA graphics card to another one that has a Radeon HD 7730M graphics card. I deleted my NVIDIA drivers and used the default drivers as the NVIDIA drivers caused issues, but a game that used to run decently now runs sluggishly, and I'm trying to get drivers for my Radeon graphics card.

I went to here: https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx and downloaded the Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 18.10 for Ubuntu 16.04.4, and installed them. I then ran

`sudo apt-get install firmware-amd-graphics`

and

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
```

Except it still doesn't work.

```
seedship@destiny:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Chelsea LP [Radeon HD 7730M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 driver: FAILED: amdgpu
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.02hz
           GLX Renderer: N/A GLX Version: N/A
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to see why it failed.

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | tail -n 60
```

shows the actual sequence of events leading up to the failure, but in this case, it's pretty likely that you failed to update /etc/X11/xorg.conf and change the driver from nvidia to amdgpu. It's also possible that your card does not work right with the amdgpu driver. But if your xorg.conf shows nvidia still, which it should, xorg will fail, since you are telling to do an impossible thing.

Most distribution driver packages have always had the glaring and obvious failure to actually check xorg.conf to make sure that it can even work, and also fail to update it when required, and to let users know that this is required, which is largely incomprehensible in this day and age given that the role of software is supposed to be to do this type of checking automatically. And good software does, but distro packages sadly have rarely done this right.

So you have to do  a sequence of tests, first, verify that nvidia is not listed as the driver in xorg.conf, then, after changing that if it said nvidia, you have to see why the amdgpu failed, if it still fails.

To make matters more complicated, some systems will add in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ files that you have to also check for, all of which is why I stopped personally doing graphics support in real time, too many ways it can be done wrong.